# How to run a JAR application as a different user in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, executable-jar, user-permissions

I would like to choose the user for run configuration so that my application runs with reduced permissions.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any option available for this in Intellij.
Only way I can think of so far is to run as "Shell script" and clean/package my JAR in "before launch" configuration. This however requires a lot of manual configuration and cannot be used to run tests. It becomes even more annoying when the user has a password (which could be stored in Intellij's configuration like database passwords for example).

I've found the ["shorten command line" option](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/10/intellij-idea-2017-3-eap-configurable-command-line-shortener-and-more/) but I don't see any way to add my own configuration. If I could, it would be something like:

```
sudo -u nobody java [options] className [args]
```

Answer (score 0):

If program can be run via command line - you can try using [External Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.2/configuring-third-party-tools.html) to run it.

Comment: Is it possible to add an External Tool to run configuration?

Comment: No, please vote for this request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104897